# ProxyPass: Mixed Content in Laravel HTTPS

Tags: laravel, ssl, https

I'm using `Laravel 5.8`

Currently I have this site: sample name

https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet

and

I have this site: sample name

http://my-aws-public-ip/login

Using `Proxy Pass` included in my `myssldomain.com` when the users triggers/search for this link : https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet/login

the browser will load the content of this site http://my-aws-public-ip/login

The `proxy pass` works fine but the problem is the `styles` and `javascript` is not loaded and the browser says `Mixed Content` because the `my-aws-public-ip` site is loaded as HTTP not HTTPS

Currently

I changed my `config/app.php` as

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet/'),
```

and

my

`.env` file I changed the `APP_URL` to this `https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet/`

**What I tried**

Also

I followed this steps but seems not working too.

https://coderwall.com/p/g9qkea/mixed-content-issue-content-must-be-served-as-https-in-laravel

Also I tried to change the following just to solve the problem

`APP_ENV=production`

`APP_DEBUG=false`

`APP_URL=https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet/`

and add this code at the beginning of `web.php`

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

But still not working on my side.
Is there anything I need to setup just to make sure this will work?

**Expected**

[image]

**Using proxy pass from myssldomain.com**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my own problem! Since the proxy uses HTTPS and Laravel uses HTTP Request as default you may try to config it to HTTPS.

*Like this*

**config/app.php**

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet'),
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', 'https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet'),
```

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=XX
APP_ENV=XXX
APP_KEY=base64:XXX
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet
```

**app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot()
{
    if (env('APP_ENV') !== 'local') {
        $this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);
    }
}
```

**routes/web.php**

At the beginning of codes add this;

```
URL::forceRootUrl('https://www.myssldomain.com/ewallet');
```

**After doing this, your CSS/JS will be loaded as HTTPS not HTTP anymore.**

Comment: You just saved me from hell. Thank you.